# Github webhook error: We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout

Tags: github, webhooks

[image]

I tested **curl** and **postman** with the same payload URL and payload body I had in **Github settings/hooks tab**.

It works well in curl and postman but It doesn't work on Github settings/hooks with with errors such as service timeout.

ps. I used Github enterprise host, API and repositories.

Answer (score 3):

The reason was an **unacceptable port** on my enterprise github instance.
It works well with changing to the valid port my enterprise github allowed.
Thanks, bglee

Comment: Where can this be changed?

Comment: I couldn't change the acceptable ports for the Github Enterprise instance I was working against, so I took the generally advisable step of putting an `nginx` reverse proxy on the jenkins instance so I could use clean URLs without specifying a port: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I will give the complete description of how I made it work.
I am assuming that you have a AWS EC2 server which is supposed to listen to your github. If you wish to do the same on localhost, you will need to forward the port using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

The listener for the same is-

```
import web as webpy

urls = ('/.*', 'hooks')

app = webpy.application(urls, globals())

class hooks:
    def POST(self):
        data = webpy.data()
        print ('\nDATA RECEIVED:')
        print (data)
        return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Save this as listen.py and install dependencies using pip. (Make sure you use pip3 for python3). The web module for python3 can be installed via-

```
pip3 install web.py==0.40-dev1
```

Connect to your server using SSH and run

```
python3 listen.py 1234
```

This will initiate the listener on port 1234(Make sure to make this port open in your AWS security groups)

Now your server is setup and ready to listen on port 1234. Check the same using postman. If the listener replies with-

```
DATA RECEIVED:
b''
157.51.203.128:49935 - - [26/May/2018 14:46:43] "HTTP/1.1 POST /" - 200 OK
```

then you are all set to go and configure your github webhook.

Go to the webhook and ensure the configurations are

Payload URL: http://ServerIpV4PublicIp:1234/
Content type: application/json
Secret:
select- Send Everything
Select Active

Now update/save the webhook and try pushing to your github repository, and wait for the server to listen and print the json file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your tip and used Postman to mimic the Github web hook. It also worked for me. The next commit I pushed to my repo *did* trigger a valid web hook without any changes. Now all is good in Webhookland.

Answer (score 0):

When I change the port number to other than `8080` and running jenkins like:

`java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081`

I am not able to deliver payload via github webhook while jenkins is **up** but strangely, after I am **quitting** the jenkins server using `CTRL+C` the payload is delivering.

Now when I change the port back to `8080` and deliver the payload via webhook, it is successful while jenkins is up and running only.